# find the "Query String Parameters" of an url from .aspx page for scrape

Tags: asp.net, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am using `beautifulsoup` and `requests` python libraries for scraping. Normally, the URL of the target page can be seen on the browser. But sometimes it is not seen in the browser, so it can be learned by the Developer Tools>Network tabs `Query String Parameters` from Chrome easily.

But I can't find the "Query String Parameters" of the https://www.imo-official.org/search.aspx page.

Is there anyone help me how to find the parameters of the "searching any value" on this page?

Comment: The page gets POSTed with search parameters. You wont find it in querystring, when you click the "search" button.

Comment: I think it will be possible to get the result by querystring in URL like clicking seacrh button. For ex: https://www.internationalparceltracking.com/#/search is our target page. We can get the search result by adding end of the URL with `?barcode=3SABC1234567890&checkIfValid=true&country=CL&language=de` parameters. So i want to learn, what is the similar parameters for aspx pages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes a POST request but you need to make a prior request to pick up the cookies and certain values for the body to post. An example for a contestant search. You can view this in the network tab. You would want to develop the below with error handling.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

data = {
  '__VIEWSTATE': '',
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': '',
  '__EVENTVALIDATION': '',
  'ctl00$CPH_Main$TextBox1': '',
  'ctl00$CPH_Main$Button1': 'Search',
  'ctl00$CPH_Main$CheckBox_Contestant': 'on',
  'ctl00$CPH_Main$DropDownListFrom': '1959',
  'ctl00$CPH_Main$DropDownListTo': '2019'
}

def get_results(search_term):
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get('https://www.imo-official.org/search.aspx')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        d = {i['id']:i['value'] for i in soup.select('[type="hidden"]')}
        for k,v in d.items():
            data[k]=v
        data['ctl00$CPH_Main$TextBox1'] = search_term
        r = s.post('https://www.imo-official.org/search.aspx', data=data)
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        df = pd.read_html(str(soup.select('table')[1]))[0]
        return df

print(get_results('Zhuo Qun Song'))
```

Comment: your code work exactly, what i tried `request = requests.post(url,files=formdata)` and didn't get the correct response. So I understood that I need to learn more about `post`. so what do you advise to understand the logic/rule of `post`???

Comment: aspx pages expect some validation/addit info to be passed in this case viewstate etc and session cookie so you need to pick these up from prior GET and pass with POST.

Answer (score 0):

You don't see a querystring because the search button sends a `POST` request in this case. You see query strings like `?q=cats` in `GET` requests.

You can send `POST` requests using `requests` like this:

```py
url = "https://example.com"
formdata = {name:'jon',age:'21'}
response = requests.request(method='POST',url=url,data=formdata)
```

Go to Network tabs, and you can find form data, and other values you might want to pass as arguments.

You can read more at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_requests_post.asp)